# how to move from android studio 1.3 to 1.5

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio 1.3 and I have downloaded the update android studio 1.5 when its appear in update now I have both version on my machine but my projects still  open in android studio 1.3 . I want to use android studio 1.5 , Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [tools website](http://tools.android.com/download/studio) download the most recent version in the stable branch for the android studio

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Android Studio 1.3 Help and update from there:-

Help-> Check for the Update -> update

Select Stable Channel

Comment: I did and downloaded the android studio 1.5  and run the setup and it worked fine first time and now when I open android studio it open older version only

Comment: @DeepakRai, are bhai just do as I wrote. It will never create problem.

Comment: I am asking the steps after downloading the patch